# How to get multiple <td> values in single xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am stuck in creating xpath which is under TR tag and
i want to get the value of td[2], td[3], td[4] and td[5] from each TR tag. See below HTML.

```
<tbody>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td><img src="/Content/Uploaded//Profile//MasterAdmin/ashishadmin/95.jpg" class="profilepic img-responsive img-circle"></td>
      <td>Ashish A Admin</td>
      <td>ashishad@mailinator.com</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>ashishadmin</td>
      <td><label class="chkcontainer pointer-none"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" checked="checked"><span class="checkmark"></span> </label></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i></td>
      <td><a href="/Admin/Admin/SaveMasterAdmin/47" class="btn btn-success m-l-5">Edit</a><a href="#" class="btn delete btn-danger m-l-5" onclick="DeleteData(this,47);">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>

   <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td><img src="/Content/Uploaded//Profile//MasterAdmin/shpatel/download.jpg" class="profilepic img-responsive img-circle"></td>
      <td>Shree A Patel</td>
      <td>shpatel@mailinator.com</td>
      <td>8767676766</td>
      <td>shpatel</td>
      <td><label class="chkcontainer pointer-none"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" checked="checked"><span class="checkmark"></span> </label></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i></td>
      <td><a href="/Admin/Admin/SaveMasterAdmin/31" class="btn btn-success m-l-5">Edit</a><a href="#" class="btn delete btn-danger m-l-5" onclick="DeleteData(this,31);">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>

   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td><img src="/content/custom/img/default-user.jpg" class="profilepic img-responsive img-circle"></td>
      <td>Ashish G Savaliya</td>
      <td>ashish@mailinator.com</td>
      <td>7897897890</td>
      <td>asavaliya</td>
      <td><label class="chkcontainer pointer-none"><input type="checkbox" class="chk" checked="checked"><span class="checkmark"></span> </label></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i></td>
      <td><a href="/Admin/Admin/SaveMasterAdmin/32" class="btn btn-success m-l-5">Edit</a><a href="#" class="btn delete btn-danger m-l-5" onclick="DeleteData(this,32);">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Want to create xpath of the only 2,3,4, and 5 TD values from each row. see below image of all the required data which i want to print using the xpath.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, what was the output of your trial and what is the expected one?

Comment: Tried this xpath "//tr[@role='row']/td[2]" but it gave only second <TD> value and i want to get 2, 3, 4, and 5th td value. Like "//tr[@role='row']/td[2] [3] [4] [5]"

Comment: Expected output: 
From first TR >> Ashish A Admin    ashishad@mailinator.cm      ashishadmin
From Second TR >>  Sherr A Patel      Shpatel@mailinator.com     8767676766     shpatel
From Third TR >> Ashish G Savaliya ashish@mailinator.com 7897897890 asavaliya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//tr/td[position() >= 2 and position() <= 5]
```

Comment: Can we use inbetween method in this?

Comment: @AshishSavaliya I'm not aware of any operator or function called `inbetween` in XPath 1.0.